# Trouble parsing HTML with CURL, DOMXPath, PHP and iterating into an array

Tags: php, curl, xpath, domxpath

I know it's probably my lack of experience with PHP, but I've been working on the same thing for like 5 hours now. I'm so fed up with it.

I'm able to return the 10 links I'm scraping, but I can't seem to figure out how to turn into an array.

I've read hundreds of posts about how it is and isn't possible, and that the dom object is unable to pass into an array.. I've tried tons of different workarounds and nothing seems to work.

My main reason for my perseverance is this article:
http://martinsikora.com/parsing-html-pages-using-xpath
He seems to have accomplished it.

Feel like I've worked too much on it now to give up.

Is there another way to accomplish this that I'm totally missing?

```
<?php
    $curl = curl_init('http://www.notgoogle.com/search?q=Las+Vegas+Burgers');
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/8.0.552.224 Safari/534.10' );

    $html = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    if (!$html) {
        die( "something's wrong!" );
    }

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

    $result = $xpath->query('//h3//a//@href');

    foreach($result as $node)
    {
        echo "{$node->nodeName} - {$node->nodeValue}";
    }
```

#### Output:

```
href - http://vegasmagazine.com/dining/articles/guide-the-very-best-burgers-in-townhref     - http://www.vegasburgerblog.com/href - http://www.yelp.com/c/las-vegas/burgershref - http://grindburgers.com/href - http://www.burger-bar.com/lv_main.phphref - http://www.e2hospitality.com/blt-burger-las-vegas/href - http://www.bachiburger.com/href - http://www.iloveburgers.com/href - http://www.stripburger.com/href - http://www.lbsburger.com/href - http://www.lasvegasweekly.com/news/2013/may/09/10-burgers-eat-right-now/href - http://www.urbanspoon.com/f/18/1708/Las-Vegas/Burger-Jointshref - http://www.gayot.com/restaurants/best-lasvegas-nv-top10-burgers_4lv.htmlhref - http://local.yahoo.com/NV/Las+Vegas/Food+Dining/Restaurants/Burgershref - http://govegas.about.com/od/dining/tp/bestburgers.htmhref - http://www.venetian.com/Las-Vegas-Restaurants/Casual-Dining/I-Love-Burgers/href
```

Though I've changed it so much from random articles/advice. Tried basically every hack mentioned in the PHP manual. Though I'm a total beginner, so I've probably missed something

Comment: You can convert the links in DOM to a JSON array and accordingly decode it using the json_decode function in php. This will give you an array.

Comment: thank you. I knew the results he was getting looked like json, but I don't see where he's doing that within the code?

Comment: My Mistake i missed the CURL part of the query. You wont be able to do it as per my approach instead the approach you are trying is one of the best.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: As per the example specified in the link provided, the data is being stored into the scores[][] array.

Comment: So what am I missing then?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a violation if Google's ToS...

Comment: Anyone involved in SEO unfortunately almost always violates their ToS. They can contact me directly if they have a problem with it, and I could also disable my Adwords spend.